# Times New Roman in LaTeX plus fancy header w/o page number on first page.

Tags: fonts, header-footer

Below is my file.  I am trying to make sure that I am in 12pt Times New Roman font. Also, I am trying to get rid of the page number on this first page without getting rid of the header.  If anyone has any suggestions for ensuring these two features in the document, it would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\rhead{John Doe \\ #########}

Hello, world!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

- Q1. Times: `\usepackage{mathptmx}`
- Q2. Is a bit harder. The simplest solution (but not the best) would be to write in the preamble something like

```
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\AtBeginDocument{\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, Times ≠ Times New Roman.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *none* of the Times-like fonts available for TeX are Times or Times New Roman `:)`

Comment: "Times" seems to me to be an Umbrella term, containing e.g., Times New Roman, Times Ten, Times Europa, and even Nimbus Roman L which TeX offers. (For that matter, TeX Gyre Termes seems to me to be a form of Times.) Or does the word "Times" have some kind of legal status when not referring to the newspaper?

Comment: I've been doing fonts for like 5 years now and I swear I can't tell any Times from the other (and no, I can't tell Helvetica from Arial either), so I highly doubt your average academia professor or upper manager can tell a difference.

Comment: @frabjous: IIRC, "Times Roman" and "Time New Roman" both are registered by Linotype and Monotype respectively.

Comment: Thanks, though that doesn't settle "Times" alone. I can tell the difference between italic lowercase z's between Nimbus and TNR. I think that's it.

Comment: (Helvetica and Arial on the other hand, I can easily tell apart.)